# Can "was" be followed by "how"?

Tags: grammar

Can "was" be followed with "how" in an English sentence. example "Thing I did not understand was how you did it".

Comment: The "was" followed by "how" part looks fine. The start of the sentence could do with some editing, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with 'how' following 'was'. (You do have an error in that there should be either a definite or indefinite article in the first part of the sentence).

In the corrected version:

> The thing I did not understand

is a phrase which is the subject of the sentence

> was

is the verb, and

> how you did it

is the object phrase. Your sentence is not structurally different from

> The animal [subject phrase] was [verb] a lion [object phrase].

Comment: As an aside, English is a complex enough language that for virtually any two words it is possible to construct a correct sentence in which they appear next to each other.